# facebook comments plugin not working on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, plugins, comments, xfbml

I'm trying to get the facebook comments plugin working on my aspx page..but it is not appearing on the page.

I am using the Facebook.NET api from codeplex for authorization.  I inserted the code that was generated from the Facebook Comments plugin page...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>    
            <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId={MyApp's ID}&amp;amp;xfbml=1"></script>
            <div>
                <fb:comments numposts="15" width="425" publish_feed="true"></fb:comments>
            </div>
```

I can see that the script is retrieved by inspecting the resulting html code in firebug...but can't figure out why the plugin is not being rendered...

any help is appreciated...thx

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found out the solution,

It seems that the  tag should be within the   element.

just move the script tag within the  and it will work

Following code worked for me.

```
  <div id="fb-root">
       <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=__YOUR_APP_KEY_HERE&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
  </div>
```

by doing the above i got the comments box to show up....

Now the problem is that, when i click on the POST Button, it doesn't post it... have to figure out why... anyone has solution for this ?

Comment: I what you suggested, and it still doesn't work.  I am using the facebook.net api from codeplex...is that what you are using?